# What is a finger bow?

Tags: double-bass, bow

Today, a fellow double bassist, sent me this 'finger bow' :

[image]

What is the purpose of such a thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The “Finger Bow” allows the player to instantly switch between finger style (pizzicato), and bowing (arco) with a flick of a finger. The bow is 10 3/8” long, and made of lightweight and resonate poplar wood. It is not intended to replace a traditional longer bow but to be a new tool for creative expression.

-[Finger Bow website](http://expandinghandsmusic.com/ehm1_005.htm)

Just an easier way to switch between finger style and bowing.

Comment: Is this used to play short arco passages or is it used like a normal bow?

Comment: It's not intended to replace a normal bow, so I assume it's used for short arco passages in primarily pizzicato pieces.  That doesn't prevent you from using it in longer arco passages.